# Some keys on keyboard map to numbers instead

Tags: usb, system-installation, keyboard-layout

I'm running Leenux 5.1 from a USB stick using unetbootin. It works ok, except my keyboard is messed up -- pressing <kbd>k</kbd> results in a `2` instead (the <kbd>2</kbd> key also types a `2`). How could this happen?

Comment: Sounds like the numlock is being turned on.

Comment: Thanks Kevin.  You are right.  By pressing the fn key and f11 I can now type my k.  Strange that it gets turned on during boot up.  Now I have too find out how to close windows.

Comment: @Kevin Post as an answer? I'm tempted to call this too localized, but I guess it could happen to someone else

Answer (score 3):

The numlock was being turned on at boot, <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>f11</kbd> turns it off, allowing the right side of the keyboard to be used normally. (key combo to turn it off may be different on other keyboards)